# How do I find out how many Office365 / Office 2016 Business installs my account is allowed?

Tags: office365, microsoft-office-2016

I set up an Office 2016 Business subscription about a year ago. At the time I only needed it on one PC; now it'd be useful to have it on two. I don't remember how many installs my account was allowed and I'm finding it hard to find out how many my subscription is allowed.

For example:

- The "Install status" page tells me only how many I have, not how many I'm allowed.
- "Organisational profile" says only:

  > - Release track:    Standard release
  > - Release track users:  All
- The install page says this, but doesn't say whether I *need* to:

  > Want to deactivate Office on one computer and install it on another? Go to My account > Install status.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of Office365 Business admin page. If you're both an account administrator and a user, it can get a little confusing:

- The ones with the black navigation bar on the right, with URLs like https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home, and a title **Admin Centre**, are for the overall subscription, and tell you how many *users* and *licenses* you have. These pages are intended for administrators.
- The ones with the blue navigation bar on the left, with URLs like https://portal.office.com/Account and a title **My account**, are for one user, and tell you how many *installs* and *devices* that user has. These pages seem to be intended for end users.

For me, my subscription had one user and **one license**, and that user had up to **five installs** allowed.

---

### On the "Admin Centre" pages with the black nav bar

There are two ways on the online Office365 admin pages:

- Under "Billing" in the left-hand navigation menu then "Licenses"
- Under "Billing" in the left-hand navigation menu then "Subscriptions"

Both list the number of licenses available and how many are assigned.

Also, if you click "Add user" it'll tell you if you have any available licences or if you need to buy a new one.

### On the "My Account" pages with the blue nav bar

To access your user account pages from the Admin Centre, click on your username in the top right corner of the screen then "View account".

- The home page has a handy info box that explains very simply how many installs *this user* is allowed on their one license:

  [image]
- That Manage Installs page is also on the nav bar, with the title **Install Status**.